# Pass object data to Public_Activity record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [Public Activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) rails gem to create a activity feature for my rails/angular app.

I have tracked my movie model,

```
include PublicActivity::Model
tracked owner: -> (controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
```

And in the activity_controller I have,

```
def index
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => @activities.to_json(include: :owner)
    end
  end
end
```

When a user adds a movie the gem creates a new trackable record in the activities table,

```
create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "trackable_id"
  t.string   "trackable_type"
  t.integer  "owner_id"
  t.string   "owner_type"
  t.string   "key"
  t.text     "parameters"
  t.integer  "recipient_id"
  t.string   "recipient_type"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

The output of my activity_controller looks like this,

```
{"id":3,"trackable_id":6,
  "trackable_type":"Movie",
  "owner_id":1,
  "owner_type":"User",
  "key":"movie.create",
  "parameters":{},
  "recipient_id":null,
  "recipient_type":null,
  "created_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z",
  "owner":{
    "id":1,
    "email":"jon@doe.nl",
    "name":"Jon Doe"
    }
}
```

I would like to add the data of the movie that's been added to this record as well.

So for example when I would add the movie Creed, the activity record would look like this,

```
{"id":3,"trackable_id":6,
  "trackable_type":"Movie",
  "owner_id":1,
  "owner_type":"User",
  "key":"movie.create",
  "parameters":{},
  "recipient_id":null,
  "recipient_type":null,
  "created_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z",
  "owner":{
    "id":1,
    "email":"jon@doe.nl",
    "name":"Jon Doe"
    },
  "movie":{
    "id":1,
    "title":"Creed",
    "release_date":"2016-01-21"
    }
}
```

Could this be done somehow?

In the [railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) Ryan can output the data about the activity like this.

```
<%= render_activity activity %>
```

I found that by using this code in my movie model I can add a parameter to the activity record.

```
tracked :params => {
  :title => "Creed",
}
```

Now when I add a new movie (and a new activity) it adds this to the controller,

```
"parameters":{"title":"Creed"}
```

Ofcourse this is hardcoded and it should be the title of the movie object. Also this doesn't look like a good way to go about this. Since I'm duplicating data.

Comment: What do you need the movie entry in your activity for? Do you want to be able to search it later or is it just for presentation?

Comment: I am using angularjs to show the data through a ng-repeat. For that I need to include the data in the activity model.

Answer (score 0):

The public_activity gem records actions you take on model that you 'track', this model is then referred to with the :trackable symbol in the activity model.

In your case the Movie model is being 'tracked' and can be accessed in the to_json call using the :trackable symbol.

```
render json: @activities.to_json(include: [:owner, :trackable])
```

This will return render the activities as a json object that looks like this:

```
{"id":3,"trackable_id":6,
  "trackable_type":"Movie",
  "owner_id":1,
  "owner_type":"User",
  "key":"movie.create",
  "parameters":{},
  "recipient_id":null,
  "recipient_type":null,
  "created_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-12-30T12:31:24.765Z",
  "owner":{
    "id":1,
    "email":"jon@doe.nl",
    "name":"Jon Doe"
   },
  "trackable":{
    "id":1,
    "title":"The Godfather",
    "release_date":"2016-01-21"
   },
  "trackable_id": 
}
```

Note that the movie is stored under the "trackable" key and not under "movie".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: Hi @mikias. Sorry for any inconvenient. It looked like a comment than an answer for me. I will check them carefully next time... Cheers mate

Comment: No problem @GileadKenzo. I appreciate the feedback, it'll help me improve my future answers. :)